# 'Greyed out' questions and answers

Tags: discussion

Already a question and answer for this, but recently I see q&a that have positive votes, so having -3 votes can't be the reason. Anybody like to enlighten?

(like this one: [1964 JB Hutto Airline Res-o-glass body composition](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/82820/45266))

Comment: It's a bit difficult to guess without screenshot, but if it's on the question list, then the biggest possibility is that the question is on [your ignored tags](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/tag-notifications/current)... if it's on the Q&A page itself, then the question might be deleted when you're reading it (small chance because you said the Q&A have positive votes).

Comment: I've noticed this on the low-scoring posts, but I've yet to see it on any positively-scored posts. I  think the general rule is -3 score or below, but there must be some exceptions or something.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot. I have various reasons for things being greyed out on some sites, and Andrew has listed the ones I would expect

Comment: @DoktorMayhem - right now, the post eludes me, bt as soon as one appears, I'll earmark it for you.

Comment: Yeah - just pop it here and ping me, or in chat, and I'll have a good look

Comment: @DoktorMayhem - '1964 JB Hutto...' is the latest greyed out - with+2 votes.

Comment: There's one greyed with 2 votes, on hold, and another with no votes. Still doesn't figure.

Comment: @Tim Admittedly, I don't see the greying-out on that question, though... (the Hutto one)... Did a grey answer get deleted from it since you saw it?

Comment: @DoktorMayhem - ironically, my question appears greyed out now! But another has just appeared - 22 mins old, 5 views, 1 answer, no dvs. About guitar action. Help!

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see what you see on that specific one so I went looking.

On Sports.SE I have a few tags I like to avoid, which means I see the Questions list like this:

[image]

If this is what you are seeing then it is because of your Ignored Tags list. Can you guess what mine are on Sports? :-)

If however you see yellow colour coding, like this:

[image]

Then it is from having a gold badge for that tag. (Earn at least 1000 total score for at least 200 non-community wiki answers in the tag)

And if you see pink colour coding, that indicates deleted posts - you have enough rep to see them. I'm not going to copy any up here, but they should be obvious.

If you want to check on your ignored tags, look in the right hand side bar - you should have something like this:

[image]

Comment: "yellow colour coding" that's the first time I've ever heard about color code based on a badge, not favorite tags?

Comment: It is tag based - that kind of badge is based on tag score. I have a gold badge for the guitar tag.

Comment: Wasn't even aware of the 'ignored tag' list. So probably the other idea of my gold badge - does it subtly mean 'don't bother providing an answer to this'? Thanks for your support.

Comment: I asked about 'ignored' tags. I haven't done anything that I'm aware of - so are they automatic. If not, how do I restore  all tags?

Comment: Edited to include that info @Tim